# why is city the only field I can geocode on in my fusion table?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-fusion-tables

I just uploaded my first xls file into a Google Fusion table.  It has the fields: ID, Address, City, State, and ZIP.

For example:

```
address = 121 e main st
city = hartselle
state = AL
ZIP = 35640
```

When I choose File -> Geocode from the fusion tables menu, the only column choice in the Geocode pop-up is City.  This will generate a map, but it will place the icon at hartselle rather than 121 E Main St.

Is there a way I can geocode on address and zip or something other than city by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine address into one column.

Comment: I was able to geocode after combining address, city and state into a new column.  I hate to de-normalize my data though.